# .Net : Do static constructors get called when a constant is access?

Tags: c#, static, static-constructor

So here is what I'm thinking...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public const string MyConstant = "MyConstantValue";

    private static MyClass DefaultInstance;

    static MyClass()
    {
         DefaultInstance = new MyClass();
    }
}

...

NotificationService.RegisterForNotification(MyClass.MyConstant, Callback);
```

Will this work or do I need to use something like a `static readonly` <del>property</del> field to trigger the static constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of a constant doesn't necessarily result in a member access which would cause the static constructor to be called.  The compiler is allowed to (encouraged, even) substitute the value of the constant at compile time.

Your suggested workaround of `static readonly` should be ok, although `readonly` suggests a field, not a property.  Properties are read-only when they have no setter, the `readonly` keyword isn't involved.

A simple example:

```
class HasSConstructor
{
    internal const int Answer = 42;
    static HasSConstructor()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("static constructor running");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + HasSConstructor.Answer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output under .NET 4.0:

> The answer is 42

The static constructor never runs!

Comment: you are correct about the property/field comment, I tend not to differentiate most of the time, which is probably going to get me into trouble one of these days.

Answer (score 3):

Static constructor is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced. See here: [MSDN: Static Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

By the way, constant fields are inherently static, but as pointed they may (and probably will) be substituted by the value itself.

Comment: It's "**immediately** before".  C# classes with static constructors are never marked `beforefieldinit`.  But using a constant (called a `literal` in .NET) doesn't access a static member.

Answer (score 1):

The static constructor will not be called if you're just accessing public constants. For example, consider this class:

```
class Testo
{
    public const string MyValue = "Hello, world";
    public static readonly int xyzzy;

    static Testo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In static constructor");
        xyzzy = 27;
    }
}
```

Now, in another class, execute:

```
Console.WriteLine(Testo.MyValue);
Console.WriteLine(Testo.xyzzy);
```

Your output will be:

```
Hello, world
In static constructor
27
```

Constants are hoisted from the class at compile time. So the value of `Testo.MyValue` does not reference the `Testo` class at runtime. The static constructor is not called until you call something that requires initialization.

So, yes, you need to access something like a `static readonly` if you want to ensure that the constructor is called.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need such. Static constructor is called when the class is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, and when is a class loaded?

Comment: Either there is a reference to that class (such as accessing a static member, instantiating an object, casting to that class) or you manually load that class.

Comment: @Nam: That's not right.  Casting or manually loading a class isn't allowed to run the *type initializer* if the type isn't marked with `beforefieldinit`, and C# classes with static constructors aren't marked `beforefieldinit`.

Comment: How do you manually load a class? And casting doesn't necessarily call static constructor: `public static explicit operator Foo(Bar bar){ return null; }`. Calling this cast doesn't.